# Curl request with basic authorization not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to call api to retrieve token but it's not working. I have tried diff. ways to pass parameters but curl request returns nothing.

This is my code that i am trying. But it returns nothing.

```
$xurl = 'https://test-api.authtest.com/oauth2/token';
$userName = '76556789000023';
$password = '1hjgtyudkportd4451test';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $xurl,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
      'grant_type' => 'password'
    ],
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_USERPWD  => $userName . ':' . $password,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Content-Type: application/json" ),
));
$response_received = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl))
    $response_received=curl_error($curl);
else
    curl_close($curl);
var_dump($response_received);
echo "<br><br>";
print_r("<b>response_received</b><br>".$response_received);
```

Comment: `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE)` gives what?

Comment: I am confused. Now is that an attempt to use http basic auth, or is it an attempt to use oauth2, as the URL suggests?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do a OAuth2 Password Grant (which is deprecated) and from you explicitly setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` I assume the endpoint wants a JSON.

In this case, you need to adjust your code as follows:

```php
$xurl = 'https://httpbin.org/anything';
$userName = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$curl = curl_init();

$postdata = json_encode(array(
    'username' => $userName,
    'password' => $password,
    'grant_type' => 'password'
));

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $xurl,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Content-Type: application/json" ),
));

var_dump(curl_exec($curl));

if(curl_errno($curl)) {
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);
```

This has the following changes:

- not sending credentials as `Basic-Auth`, as the server wont understand this
- sending an actual JSON body with the username, password and grant type
- add `CURLOPT_HEADER` setting to make sure we see the HTTP response headers in the response from `curl_exec()`
- to debug what you are sending, I changed the `$xurl` to httpbin.org, just change those values back

If you need more docs on the OAuth2 Password Grant, this might be helpful: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/

Comment: I have tried this. But it's returning string(0) in var_dump

Comment: Hmm, I updated my answer to add the `CURLOPT_HEADER` setting which makes sure that `curl_exec()` returns the HTTP response headers as well, so you should see something now. If this does not work, try with my script against httpbin.org. If this works, you might need to contact the API vendor and ask for documentation for how to interact with their API

Comment: I have tried with CURLOPT_HEADER and it returns response string(555) "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: This is the point where you need to either find a documentation on that API or talk to the people that build it in order to understand how to properly communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. This is solution. I have used http_build_query() and CURLOPT_USERPWD

```
$xurl = 'https://test-api.authtest.com/oauth2/token';
$userName = '76556789000023';
$password = '1hjgtyudkportd4451test';

$postdata = [
    'username' => $userName,
    'password' => $password,
    'grant_type' => 'password'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userName . ":" . $password);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
curl_close($ch);
```